# How to load referenced COLLADA files in ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I want to load collada files from an export. The files are exported in such a way, that the "base" file references another collada file with the actual geometry.

The base file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<COLLADA version="1.5.0" xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2008/03/COLLADASchema">
  <asset>
    <contributor>
      <author>ACME</author>
    </contributor>
    <created>2016-04-27T14:53:24</created>
    <modified>2016-04-27T14:53:24</modified>
    <unit meter="0.001" name="mm" />
    <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
  </asset>
  <library_visual_scenes id="libvisualscenes">
    <visual_scene id="libvisualscenes.scene">
      <node id="38760" name="Part1_CATPart">
        <matrix>-1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -399.679153 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 671.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000</matrix>
        <instance_node url="Part1_CATPart_799.dae#acme_frame_self_origin" />
      </node>
    </visual_scene>
  </library_visual_scenes>
  <scene>
    <instance_visual_scene url="#libvisualscenes.scene" />
  </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

*Part1_CATPart* is referenced in the collada above. 
I tried the naive approach and loaded this collada using the ColladaLoader2.js, but this led to the error `ColladaLoader2.js:175 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'build' of undefined`. Loading *Part1_CATPart* directly works. However, this way does not take the matrix of the base file into account.

Is there a method to make threejs` colladaLoader2 fetch the referenced files?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the url is parsed [here on line 2326](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js#L2326) in the parse method. Normally the url points to another node intenally. You can get the url in the if clause like this:

```
if ( iNode ) 
    this.nodes.push( ( new Node() ).parse( iNode )) ;
}else{
    url = url.split("#")[0]
    console.log(url);
}
```

Then you could use the `url` to load the child model and to add it to the scene in an `onload` callback:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var result = loader.load(url);
var scene = result.scene;

var name, model, children = scene.children;
var onLoad = function( result ){
    // process the result of each child model and add to parent scene
};
var onProgress = function(){};
loader.load( url, onLoad, onProgress );
```

**[Here is a fiddle with a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/tzf9d7Lb/3/)**

The fiddle only outputs the url. Loading it correctly I leave up to you.

Comment: The file is referenced with `<instance_node url="Part1_CATPart_799.dae#acme_frame_self_origin" />` and not with the nodes name.

Comment: Thanks, that got me thinking in the right direction.